# Using MapStruct in Android to map generic types?

Tags: java, android, generics, mapping, mapstruct

I have a scenario in which I have to convert `Resource` objects (from network requests) into `RealmObject` objects (data layer) using [MapStruct](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct) to handle the object mapping. I am attempting to create a generic `Mapper` interface to prevent having to define a custom mapper for each resource, like so:

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import io.realm.RealmObject;
import moe.banana.jsonapi2.Resource;

@Mapper
public interface ResourceMapper <T extends Resource, I extends RealmObject> {
    ResourceMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ResourceMapper.class);

    I resourceToRealm(T resource);
}
```

but this results in a build error (compilation is successful, however):

> Error:(13, 4) error: Can't generate mapping method for a generic type
>   variable source.

Is this not possible? If not, I would have to create a custom mapper for every single `Resource` and use a `switch` to tell the deserializer which mapper to use based on class type etc... it would probably get ugly and not result in very DRY code. Their [documentation](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/reference-guide/) isn't very clear on this.

Comment: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/583 seems to be still in enhancement phase for generic types

Comment: The linked issue is an enhancement for something else, not what the question is about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 1:**

From Documentation,

> The generated implementation uses plain Java method invocations for mapping between source and target objects, i.e. there is no reflection involved. By default, properties are mapped if they have the same name in source and target, but this and many other aspects can be controlled using @Mapping and a handful of other annotations.

---

I am doubtful whether it is possible for such mapper contract. 
We could not tell which type would be instantiated as the result of this auto-generation.

There are two expected outcomes

1. Generate of a class of type I *(I assume this is what you would be expecting)* - [Currently not possible](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/583)
2. Generate of a class of type RealmObject and only base method attributes and methods are mapped

Incase you want second outcome, please follow as per [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/631#issuecomment-260739674)

Comment: The linked issue with the first expected outcome is not correct. The issue there is about something else. The second outcome is what is correct. If one declares a generic mapper, MapStruct has no way of knowing which types it needs to use to generate the code. Keep in mind that MapStruct only generates mapping code and uses **no reflection** during runtime.

I am not sure if it is wise for MapStruct to generate mappings between all possible combinations of a generic mapper.

Comment: Care to checkout this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663109/mapstruct-mapping-realmlist-relationship